# Overflow: hidden and floating

Tags: css

I am trying to add overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis to a title with an image floating to the left. Please see this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xgzfb18j/

```
<li>
<a href="">×</a>
<a class="title" href=""><img src="">My very long title</a>
<dl class="variation">
  <dt>Delivery time: 1 day</dt>
</dl>
<span class="quantity">2 × <span><bdi>174,00&nbsp;<span>€</span></bdi></span>    </span>                
</li>

img{
float: left;
margin-right: 1em;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
box-shadow: none;
border:1px solid
}

.title{
display:block;
font-size:18px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

My issue is that the two text lines underneath (Delivery time and price) should be underneath the title, also to the right of the image. How can I do that?

EDIT: I only have access to the css, not the html.

Comment: you can create a div and put img and text inside then layout them as you wish

Comment: Am I right that the img and the title should be clickable but the descriptions shouldn't be? Also, if the title and descriptions are too long for the right hand side do you want the extra to float under the img ( I assume so as this is  a reason for using of float rather than flex or grid but thought I'd better check that you don't want essentially two columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note: some of the comments relate to an earlier version of this answer where I had mistakenly thought some change to the HTML would be possible. The revised answer given here is CSS only].

Using CSS grid we can define the grid areas that the four direct children of the li element are to occupy.

It is necessary to position the title element absolutely to get the alignment of the title text in line with the other two text lines (assuming that is required).

Obviously you'll have to do some alterations to get the relative (and absolute) dimensions as you want them but this is a start:

```css
li {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'x x' 'title title' 'space dl' 'space span';
}

img {
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

li a:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: x;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow-y: visible;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 110px;
  position: absolute;
}

li a:first-child {
  grid-area: x;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
}

.variation {
  grid-area: variation;
}

.quantity {
  grid-area: quantity;
}

li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'x x x' 'title title title' 'space variation variation' 'space quantity quantity';
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="">×</a>
  <a class="title" href=""><img src="">My very long title</a>
  <dl class="variation">
    <dt>Delivery time: 1 day</dt>
  </dl>
  <span class="quantity">2 × <span><bdi>174,00&nbsp;<span>€</span></bdi>
  </span>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: @A Haworth the problem is I am using Woocommerce and have no control over the html - only css.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that. Probably best to put that in your question as a constraint as I hadn't realised. It will be quite tricky keeping the img and title in the same anchor element but I'll have another think!

Comment: @ A Haworth thanks, that would be great. Could you - if you cannot find a css solution - help me with modifying the template instead?

Comment: Sorry I can't look at this for a couple of hours, but I think  I can see how to do it. Will get back to you.

Comment: Okay, I tried and tried but could not get the css to work. I think there is so much other css already that makes it difficult. I now simply edited the template and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it differently, try wrapping your data with flex and then using the flex to set the direction on each part.

```
 <li>
   <a href="">×</a>
   <div class="flex-row">
     <img src="">
     <div class="flex-column">
         <a class="title" href="">My very long title</a>
     <dl class="variation">
        <dt>Delivery time: 1 day</dt>
     </dl>
     <span class="quantity">2 × <span><bdi>174,00&nbsp;<span>€</span></bdi></span></span>       
     </div>
        
   </div>
  
</li>


        .flex-row{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .flex-column{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
}
```

If I understood you correctly